# Image is not stretched to the whole client area

Tags: wpf, xaml

Visual Studio 2012, WPF C# Windows Application. XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Edge.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Background="Blue">
        <Image Source="Images/House.png"  
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           Stretch="Fill" Margin="3"
           />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Image is not stretched to the whole window, as I want, it is shown only in 1/4 window area. I expect that `Stretch="Fill"` must stretch the image to the whole window. What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: @Clemens - this is exact copy of my XAML page, and application doesn't contain anything except of this code.

Comment: Solved - image is shown properly, it contains white area, I need to cut it off.

Comment: I believe your image has white color in it. I have tested your code on my machine, and it works fine. The image in my machine was stressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your outer `Grid`. A `Grid` will re-size to fit the size of its children, but the child in this case (the `Image`) is trying to stretch to fill the size of its parent so I'm going to guess that what you are seeing is the image being drawn actual size.

Try using a `DockPanel` instead which fills all available parent space children.

```
<Window x:Class="Edge.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel Background="Blue">
        <Image Source="Images/House.png"  
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           Stretch="Fill" Margin="3"/>
    </DockPanel> 
</Window>
```

Comment: The grid occupies the whole client area - see blue border in the picture. I need to use grid, because in real program I place the image to one grid cell - with the same result.

Comment: You're not giving Grid a width or height, a Grid will resize to fit its children. You aren't giving your Image an explicit width or height so what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the image itself - I need to cut the white area from the image. Really stupid...

Comment: @AlexFarber No worries mate, I've done a similar thing before =)

Comment: This is still a wrong answer, as the Grid behaves exactly as expected here. It will *not* resize to the size of its children. When it is in the Content of a Window, it will resize to the size of the window client area.

Comment: @Clemens I agree. The code in the question is working as expected. Not just the grid behave as expected, the properties intention is correct. This answer should not be marked as answer!